# AppleScript to make the display black and white for monteray

Tags: applescript

Can you rewrite this applescript for Monterey?

```
tell application "System Preferences" to reveal anchor "Seeing_ColorFilters" of pane "Accessibility"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"'s first window's first group's first tab group
        click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
        tell first pop up button
            click
            -- if necessary, uncomment the following line to allow time for the menu to open
            -- delay 0.1
            tell its menu
                click menu item 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

This code is a script that makes the display grayscale. I used to use this code in BigSur. However, after updating the version to Monterey, it stopped working. My Monterley version is 12.6.2.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be a timing issue. The menu that your script uses to select the greyscale option is no longer immediately available under Monterey 12.6.2. A short delay is required.

I took this script and enabled it one line at a time. With the System Preferences window already open and the color filters pane revealed, it worked all the way to the end.

So, I then ran the full script with System Preferences closed. It failed at the line:

```
click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
```

with the error:

> **Script Error**

> System Events got an error: Can’t get group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences". Invalid index.

That error sounds like the window isn’t yet available. So I tried adding a delay in front of clicking the checkbox:

```
delay 0.1
click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
```

The script then began to work as I assume you wished it to: the checkbox is checked, the first item on the menu (Greyscale) is selected, and the screen goes greyscale.

However, a hard-coded delay seems likely to fail if the system takes variable amounts of time to make the window available. So, rather than hardcode the delay, I added a loop to check for the existance of the desired checkbox:

```
repeat while not (exists checkbox "Enable Color Filters")
    delay 0.1
end repeat
click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
```

This version should work in past and future operating systems even if the timing changes, as long as the terminology remains the same.

The same technique should also work for your commented-out delay that waits for the menu to become available:

```
tell first pop up button
    click
    -- if necessary, allow time for the menu to open
    repeat while not (exists its menu)
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    tell its menu
        click menu item 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Currently, the script toggles between greyscale and no filtering. That is, if the checkbox is *already* checked, this script will uncheck it. If your purpose is to ensure that the screen is always in greyscale, as your question implies, you may wish to verify the value of the checkbox first:

```
if the value of checkbox "Enable Color Filters" is 0 then
    click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
    tell first pop up button
        click
        -- if necessary, allow time for the menu to open
        repeat while not (exists its menu)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell its menu
            click menu item 1
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

Checkboxes have a value of `0` or `1`, depending on whether they’re currently checked (1) or unchecked (0).

If, on the other hand, your goal is for the script to toggle between the two states, there’s no reason to play around with the menu if you’re toggling color filters off:

```
if the value of checkbox "Enable Color Filters" is 0 then
    click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
    tell first pop up button
        click
        -- if necessary, allow time for the menu to open
        repeat while not (exists its menu)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell its menu
            click menu item 1
        end tell
    end tell
else
    click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
end if
```

Assuming the purpose is to guarantee the screen is in greyscale, the full script might end up looking like this:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to reveal anchor "Seeing_ColorFilters" of pane "Accessibility"

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"'s first window's first group's first tab group
        -- if necessary, allow time for the checkbox to become available
        repeat while not (exists checkbox "Enable Color Filters")
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        
        --ensure that greyscale filters are enabled
        if the value of checkbox "Enable Color Filters" is 0 then
            click checkbox "Enable Color Filters"
            tell first pop up button
                click
                -- if necessary, allow time for the menu to open
                repeat while not (exists its menu)
                    delay 0.1
                end repeat
                tell its menu
                    click menu item 1
                end tell
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful explanation. I couldn't understand everything because I wasn't very familiar with programming. But I'm really grateful for your sincerity.

Can you ask a question about the code? I think the script you made is probably moving perfectly.However, there is a problem, the macro is running in the background, and the operation stops on the way.

It is selected to the accessibility display. But it doesn't move after that.
System setting are not actually pop-up and are running in the background. And my script editor freezes.

Can you find the solution?

Comment: My guess would be permissions. That is, the app that runs the macro (or the macro itself if it’s an app) doesn’t have permission to use System Events. (a) Try running whatever app runs the macro in the foreground, and see if you get an error; (b) look in System Preferences:Security & Privacy, the Privacy Pane, and the Automation item from the list on the left. Make sure your app is in the list on the right, with a checkbox. It may be best to save your *AppleScript* as an app, so that you can give the script permission without giving the full app that’s running the macro permission.

Comment: Apparently the action is stopped here.
"repeat while not (exists checkbox "Enable Color Filters")"
The script does not progress from here.
I'm not very familiar with coding, so I actually not sure if I could answer what you are looking for.
If you have any questions, please ask me again. I will do my best for you. 
Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Assuming it works fine in Script Editor—if it fails in Script Editor, it gives you an informative error—the first thing I’d do is comment out the `repeat while not…` line and the `end repeat` line. See if it’s stuck in the repeat. I’d also make liberal use of `tell me to display dialog "Made it to 1"` at various points in the script (including inside loops) to see how far it gets and how many times it loops; use `--` to comment out lines, including `display dialog` lines, temporarily.